# How to dump only a single or certain selected stats in gem5?

Tags: gem5

I've instrumented a benchmark with the `m5 resetstats` and `m5 dumpstats` M5Ops on every main loop.

However, the output for each iteration is large, and after 10k iterations I have 1Gb of stats.

But I'm only interested in a few of those stats (`numCycles`) so most are just taking up space.

How to dump just the subset of the ones that I want, or alternatively disable the ones that I don't want?

Hopefully from inside `fs.py`, but also interested in other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A patch has been merged at: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/28628/6 you can use it as shown in the commit message, e.g.:

```
gem5.opt se.py --stats-root 'system.cpu[:].dtb' --stats-root 'system.membus'
```

would lead to a stats file that contains only entries such as:

```
system.cpu0.dtb.walker.pwrStateResidencyTicks::UNDEFINED
system.cpu1.dtb.walker.pwrStateResidencyTicks::UNDEFINED
system.membus.pwrStateResidencyTicks::UNDEFINED
system.membus.trans_dist::ReadReq
```